# Meteor (React) Typescript: How to Include a unrendered HTML snipplet?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, meteor, jsx

I have a file with specific html code:

code.html

```
<script> ... </script>
```

I simply want to include the raw code in JSX, without rendering, checking, anything:

```
class Homepage extends React.Component<any,any> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>...
      { include "code.html" }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are using babel, probably https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-html-import-to-string

Comment: @ExplosionPills unfortunately not I get the error: client/main.tsx (8, 18): Cannot find module '../imports/lib/code.html'.